# PyMongo returns None even when the db shows the data

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to make a simple blog wherein I am trying to insert and fetch data from the database. Inserting data works fine but fetching data, both with `.find()` and `.find_one()` returns `None`, even though the same statement executed in the shell works.

I am trying to fetch the data across three files with the following series of codes

database.py

```
@staticmethod
def fetchdata(collection):
    Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one()
```

post.py

```
@staticmethod
def fetch_from_db():
    return Database.fetchdata('posts')
```

app.py

```
Database.initalise()
testPost = Post.fetch_from_db()
print(testPost)
```

Comment: You aren't returning anything from fetchdata

Comment: You are throwing the document returned by `find_one()` away. You need to return it like this: `return  Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one()`

Comment: @S.M.Styvane Thank You. My code works now!

Comment: @user602525 Thanks, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return statement in the fetchdata function. it should be like

```
@staticmethod
def fetchdata(collection):
    return Database.DATABASE[collection].find_one()
```

as it was not returning anything, `fetch_from_db` was not getting any data, thus giving `None` as output.

Answer (score -1):

This is a well documented question, example code:

```
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> c = MongoClient()
>>> c.test_db.test_col.find_one()
{u'test': u'document', u'x': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('5980a8fd168186e9fb46c638'), u'other': u'value'}
```

**EDIT:**

or you can write it like this if you prefer:

```
>>> c = MongoClient()
>>> db = c.test_db
>>> col = db.test_col
>>> col.find_one()
{u'test': u'document', u'x': 1, u'_id': ObjectId('5980a8fd168186e9fb46c638'), u'other': u'value'}
```

[documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one)